# Tutorial for ZAP inegration with Oracle

Tags: solidity, truffle, oracles

Oracle is a trusted third party API from which smart contract will fetch the data.

[Zap](https://www.zap.org/) is a way to monetize the data which smart contract is getting using a token called zap token.

Is there any tutorial/Github repository/Project/case study with appropriate technical explanation using all of the above tools?